# Postgresl select count(*) time-consuming

Tags: mysql, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using `spring-data-jpa` & `postgresql-9.4`.

There is a table: `tbl_oplog`. This table has about seven million rows of data, and data is need to be displayed on the front end.(paged).

I use `Spring#PagingAndSortingRepository` , and then I found that the data query was very slow. From the logs, I found that two SQL queries were issued:

```
select
    oplog0_.id as id1_8_,
    oplog0_.deleted as deleted2_8_,
    oplog0_.result_desc as result_d3_8_,
    oplog0_.extra as extra4_8_,
    oplog0_.info as info5_8_,
    oplog0_.login_ipaddr as login_ip6_8_,
    oplog0_.level as level7_8_,
    oplog0_.op_type as op_type8_8_,
    oplog0_.user_name as user_nam9_8_,
    oplog0_.op_obj as op_obj10_8_,
    oplog0_.op as op11_8_,
    oplog0_.result as result12_8_,
    oplog0_.op_time as op_time13_8_,
    oplog0_.login_name as login_n14_8_ 
from
    tbl_oplog oplog0_ 
where
    oplog0_.deleted=false
order by
    oplog0_.op_time desc limit 10
```

And:

```
 select
    count(oplog0_.id) as col_0_0_ 
from
    tbl_oplog oplog0_ 
where
    oplog0_.deleted=?
```

(The second SQL statement is used to populate the page object,which is necessary)

I found the second statement to be very time-consuming. Why does it take so long?
How to optimize? Does this happen with `Mysql`?

Or is there any other way I can optimize this requirement? (It seems that select count is inevitable).

EDIT:
I'll use another table for the demonstration(same): 
Table:
[image]

```
select count(*) from tbl_gather_log;  // count is 6300931.cost 5.408S
```

EXPLAIN select count(*) from tbl_gather_log：

```
Aggregate  (cost=246566.58..246566.59 rows=1 width=0)
  ->  Index Only Scan using tbl_gather_log_pkey on tbl_gather_log  (cost=0.43..230814.70 rows=6300751 width=0)
```

EXPLAIN ANALYSE select count(*) from tbl_gather_log:

```
Aggregate  (cost=246566.58..246566.59 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=6697.102..6697.102 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Only Scan using tbl_gather_log_pkey on tbl_gather_log  (cost=0.43..230814.70 rows=6300751 width=0) (actual time=0.173..4622.674 rows=6300936 loops=1)
        Heap Fetches: 298
Planning time: 0.312 ms
Execution time: 6697.267 ms
```

EDIT2:

TABLE:

```
create table tbl_gather_log (
    id bigserial not null primary key,
    event_level int,
    event_time timestamp,
    event_type int,
    event_dis_type int,
    event_childtype int,
    event_name varchar(64),
    dev_name varchar(32),
    dev_ip varchar(32),
    sys_type varchar(16),
    event_content jsonb,
    extra jsonb
);
```

And:

There are probably many filtering criteria supported, so i can't simply do special operations on deleted.For example, a query might be issued `select * from tbl_oplog where name like xxx and type = xxx limit 10`,so, there will be a query:`select count * from tbl_oplog where name like xxx and type = xxx` . Futhermore, i have to know exact counts. because I need to show how many pages there are on the front end.

Comment: As well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables, questions about query performance ALWAYS require the EXPLAIN for the given query.

Comment: I edited the question, I don't know if it's enough@Strawberry

Comment: Please do include the SHOW CREATE TABLE statements - otherwise we're mostly guessing.

Answer (score 1):

The second statement takes a long time because it has to scan the whole table in order to count the rows.

One thing you can do is use an index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tbl_oplog (deleted) INCLUDE (id);
VACUUM tbl_oplog;  -- so you get an index only scan
```

Assuming that `id` is the primary key, it would be much better to use `count(*)` and omit the `INCLUDE` clause from the index.

But the best is probably to use an estimate:

```
SELECT t.reltuples * freq.f AS estimated_rows
FROM pg_stats AS s
   JOIN pg_namespace AS n
      ON s.schemaname = n.nspname
   JOIN pg_class AS t
      ON s.tablename = t.relname
         AND n.oid = t.relnamespace
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL
      unnest(s.most_common_vals::text::boolean[]) WITH ORDINALITY AS val(v,id)
   JOIN LATERAL
      unnest(s.most_common_freqs) WITH ORDINALITY AS freq(f,id)
         USING (id)
WHERE s.tablename = 'tbl_oplog'
  AND s.attname = 'deleted'
  AND val.v = ?;
```

This uses the distribution statistics to estimate the desired count.

If it is just about pagination, you don't need exact counts.

Read [my blog](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-count-made-fast/) for more on the topic of counting in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I will read your blog.  But there are probably many filtering criteria supported, so ican't simply do special operations on deleted.For example, a query might be issued ‘select * from tbl_oplog where name like xxx and  type = xxx limit 10’,so, there will be a query:`select count *  from tbl_oplog  where name like xxx and  type = xxx `. Futhermore, i have to know exact counts. because I need to show how many pages there are on the front end.

Comment: You can use the method with `EXPLAIN` at the end of my blog post for arbitrary queries. And no, you don't need to show exact counts at the front end.